# ¿Como agregar 2 Widgets a un LabelWidget de un LabelFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Buenas, estoy programando en [python](/questions/tagged/python), con la libreria grafica [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter).

## Pregunta:

¿Como agregar 2 [widgets](/questions/tagged/widgets) a un `LabelWidget` de un [labelframe](/questions/tagged/labelframe)?

## Ejemplo

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Unir el [widget](/questions/tagged/widget) "Titulo lol?" y el boton Push me!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Unir los dos en el `LabelWidget` de un [labelframe](/questions/tagged/labelframe), es posible? y ¿Como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Creo que lo que quieres hacer no se puede hacer usando los widgets por defecto. En el `LabelFrame` puedes definir `text`, para el texto de la etiqueta, o `labelwidget`, para usar otro widget como un botón en forma de etiqueta. Si defines el segundo el primero no se tendrá en cuenta. Si quieres hacer eso lo tendrás que definir tú pintando un recuadro, poniento una etiqueta y un botón a mano. De todas formas, el tener un botón en el recuadro que limita el *frame* me resulta extraño ya que no se distingue bien lo que es borde y lo que es botón. En mi opinión, lo intentaría evitar.

Comment: Se propone cerrar la pregunta con el causal __"Demasiado amplia"__ por que el OP no proporciona un _ejemplo completo mínimo y verificable_ que permita ofrecer una respuesta o alternativas viables.